# Fraction can't be rational root $(>1)$ of whole number?

Tags: number-theory

I noticed that there don't seem to be any square roots of whole numbers that are

a) rational and

b) fractional.

Another way to say this is that no fractional rational number can be squared to get a whole number.  In fact I can't find a rational fractional number that can be raised to any rational power $(>1)$ that gives a whole number.  This seems odd since one can

$1)$ raise an irrational number by a rational power $>1$ to get a whole number (square root of $2$ squared;

$2$) raise a whole number by a rational power to get an  irrational number $(2^{1.5})$ or a whole number $(2^2);$

3) raise a rational fraction by a rational power $>1$ to get a rational fractional number $(\frac{2}{3} \text{ squared } = \frac{4}{9})$

4) raise fractional rational number by an irrational power to get a whole number or a fraction (using powers that are ratios of ln).

Why can't we raise a rational fraction by a rational power $(>1)$ and end up with a whole number?  Is there some kind of proof of this?

Comment: Paragraph breaks are your friend.

Comment: Hint: the square root of a positive integer $n$ is either an integer, or irrational. This is for the same reason why any rational root of $x^2 - n = 0$ must be an integer, which follows from the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you agree that

- any fraction can be written "in lowest terms" (i.e., with no common divisors of numerator and denominator except $\pm 1$).
- every positive integer can be written as a product of prime factors, and
- if a prime $p$ divides the product $a\cdot b$, then it divides either $a$ or $b$ or both,

then I can give you a proof.

Suppose 
$$
(\frac{a}{b})^2 = n
$$
where $\frac{a}{b}$ is in lowest terms and $b > 1$ and that $n$ is the smallest positive integer with this property. 
Then
$$
a^2 = n b^2
$$
Suppose that $p$ is a prime factor of $n$. Then $p$ divides the right hand side, so it divides the left hand side, $a^2$, as well. That means that it must divide $a$ as well, by the third bullet. So we can write $a = pu$ for some integer $u$. And the left hand side now has at least two factors of $p$.

So $p^2$ divides $n b^2$. There are two possibilities:

- $p^2$ divides $n$, so $n = p^2 k$, and $a^2 = p^2 u^2$. Then we can write
  $$
  \frac{u}{b} = k^2
  $$
  and $k < n$, contradicting the idea that $n$ was the smallest integer with this property.  So this case can't happen.
- $p$ divides $n$, but $p^2$ does not, so $p$ also divides $b^2$. In that case, we must have $p$ divides $b$, by the third bullet.

But now $a$ and $b$ have the common factor $p$, which contradicts the assumption that $\frac{a}{b}$ is in lowest terms.

Comment: Simpler: if $\,b>1\,$ then some prime $\,p\mid b\,$ so $\,p\mid nb^2\! = a^2,\,$ so $\,p\mid a,\,$ contra $\,a,b\,$ coprime (wlog) $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: Indeed simpler. Wish I'd thought of that before typing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Every positive rational number can be expressed uniquely as the product of *integer* powers of primes.  So for instance $2/45 = 2^13^{-2}5^{-1}$.

Squaring something in this form doubles every exponent, so $(2/45)^2 = (2^13^{-2}5^{-1})^2=2^23^{-4}5^{-2}=4/2025$.

Positive integers must be expressed as the product of positive integer powers of primes, but you can't get positive integers out of this doubling method, so it's not possible for a non-integer rational to square to -- that is, to be the square root of -- an integer.

Comment: Note to OP: when one first encounters such informal arguments one should be sure to understand how they depend quite crucially on the *existence and uniqueness* of prime factorizations of integers (and rationals), i.e. the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Typically both are used a few times in such proofs, but informal arguments often omit *explicit* mention of such. When writing a *formal* proof, it is essential to make these uses *explicit* in order to obtain a completely rigorous proof.